# How to define an alias for a property

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, c#-4.0, .net-3.5

I want to generate aliases for properties in generated code. All I could do so far was:

```
partial class Purchase
{
    public User Customer
    {
        get
        {
            return this.User;
        }

        set
        {
            this.User = value;
        }
    }
}
```

I wonder if there is any other way to define an alias in C#. The `Purchase` class was generated by Linq-to-SQL

Comment: Won't Linq2Sql let you alter mapped names?

Comment: @HenkHolterman If I do that I would have to repeat the process every time I regenerate the DBML file.

Comment: OK, if that is an issue. But your posted code _is_ making an alias. So what the actual question? Is there anything wrong with it?

Comment: @HenkHolterman nothing wrong. I just feel repeating myself when I have to say that `Customer` both gets and sets the same property and I know that are some obscure C# features and I wondered if any of them could make my code a little less verbose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible to do in C#. Property name is single identifier you can define for it.

Don't know if this is what you're searching for or not:

but you can define (say) a `Dictionary<string,object>` where `Key` is a *propertyname* and `value` is a value of the property. In this way you can define dynamic property cash, with changing property names and values *at runtime*.

or can use an [ExpandoObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dynamic.expandoobject.aspx) , if you use `C# 4.0`

Comment: In the posted code Customer _is_ an alias for User. The OP asks for other ways to do it.

Answer (score 7):

In the case that you want a different name of property to send information to JSON using newtonSoft, you can use

```
 [JsonProperty("alias_name")]
 public type YourProperty {get;set;}
```

This can help you if you don't want that your object follow the C# convention and match with the JSON object to be received or sent

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.